# Stuck with error while installing googletrans

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans

When i was trying to install googletrans using `pip install googletrans` i get the error in cmd.
I am using python 3.6 32bit
error:-

```
           error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for V
isual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\abhishek\appdata\local\
programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
 sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Abhishek\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yv7ec
6vh\\immutables\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Abhishek\\AppData\\Loca
l\\Temp\\pip-install-yv7ec6vh\\immutables\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'
"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"')
;f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\U
sers\Abhishek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i61td5hb\install-record.txt' --singl
e-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\abhishek\appd
ata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Include\immutables' Check the logs for ful
l command output.
```

is there any way to solve this error.

please help !!!!!

Comment: Download and install C++ build tools
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/cs/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: The error have nothing to do with the package. However, you may want to check this tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Answer (score 1):

**The Error Clearly States That Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ then select "Tools For Visual Studio 2019" and select "Build Tools for visual studio 2019" select your OS type and download the build tools.**

**after in your "downloads" folder you will a have program called "vs_BuildTools" start that up run through the setup then,**

**Install VS 2019 With these requirements checked:-**

[image]

**Then Install The Software and,**
**After That Reboot or Restart your computer again, then install your required package**

> This A Pretty Long Process To Run Through so make sure you have around 2-3 Hours To Setup (Depending On Your Internet and computer condition). it took me around 2 hours approx to setup everything
>
> > Dont be frustrated if this doesn't work, because this personally happened to me, then a ran through the process again and it was installed successfully.

> Hope This Will Help... If Not Let Me Know Please.

Comment: dude it is of 3.38gb

Comment: I installed this around a week ago so did not remembered it correctly @codebyAbhishekBharti. Thanks For Correcting Me.